# informix update from other table with multi joins

Tags: informix

The following query doesn't seem to work and give syntax error:

```
update const_acad_record
set const_acad_record.education_level = school_category_type.education_level
FROM school_category_type, sch_rec sch_rec
where const_acad_record.organization_ID = sch_rec.id and
sch_rec.ctgry = school_category_type.code
```

If I convert this into a sub-query as follows, it works but updates more number of records than required:

```
update const_acad_record
set education_level = (SELECT education_level
FROM school_category_type sct, sch_rec sr
where const_acad_record.organization_ID = sr.id and
sr.ctgry = sct.code)
```

(The column `education_level` comes from table `school_category_type`.)

Comment: The Informix syntax manual doesn't include the first form; there's no reason to think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically need a statement level `WHERE` clause too, to limit the number of records updated to those with a matching entry.  I think that in this example, it can take the form:

```
UPDATE const_acad_record
   SET education_level = (SELECT education_level
                            FROM school_category_type sct
                            JOIN sch_rec sr
                              ON sr.ctgry = sct.code
                           WHERE const_acad_record.organization_ID = sr.id)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT education_level
                FROM school_category_type sct
                JOIN sch_rec sr
                  ON sr.ctgry = sct.code
               WHERE const_acad_record.organization_ID = sr.id)
```

<sup>*Untested SQL*</sup>

This limits the rows update to those for which there is a matching record.  In the absence of the statement-level WHERE clause, all rows in the table (`const_acad_record`) are updated, and those without a matching entry from the `SELECT` are set to `NULL`.

If I understood the tables better, I'd probably use an IN clause in the statement-level query, such as:

```
UPDATE const_acad_record
   SET Education_Level = (SELECT education_level
                            FROM school_category_type sct
                            JOIN sch_rec sr
                              ON sr.ctgry = sct.code
                           WHERE const_acad_record.organization_ID = sr.id)
 WHERE Organization_ID IN (SELECT sr.id
                             FROM school_category_type sct
                             JOIN sch_rec sr
                               ON sr.ctgry = sct.code)
```

<sup>*Untested SQL*</sup>

Amongst other issues, it is not clear whether the column `education_level` comes from the table `school_category_type` or the table `sch_rec`; this might alter what's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Jonathan. education_level from school_category_type is update. If this is the case, which is the best query?

Regards Manohar

Comment: Check the query plans, but I'd expect the IN variant to be better.   Usually…